# How to target only Ipad device not a browser view

Tags: css

I have a requirement that i want to target only Ipad device not a browser view (**ctrl + shift + m**  : `for Mozilla`)

I am using `@media only screen and (min-device-width : 768px) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio : 1) and (orientation : portrait)` but its not working .

Answer (score 0):

Try changing "1" to "2" when specifying device pixel ratio.

```
(-webkit-device-pixel-ratio : 2)
```